# Default getters not returning values unless `getDataValue()` is used when using TypeScript in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I am not getting values from getters on my Model when using `Model.Create`. However, the values are returned if I use `Model.getDataValue()`

#### Example:

```
const created = await User.create({
   id: '1',
   firstname: 'Darth'
});

console.info(created.id, created.firstname); // values are undefined

console.info(created.getDataValue('id'), created.getDataValue('firstname') // outputs correct values
```

My understanding from doc and examples is this *should* return the values.

Using TypeScript v4.0.3 and Sequelize v6.3.5

#### Model Definition:

```
export interface UserAttributes {
    id: string;
    firstname: string;

    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}

export interface UserCreationAttributes extends Optional<UserAttributes, 'id'> {
}

export class User extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes> implements UserAttributes {
    public id: string;
    public firstname: string;

    // timestamps!
    public readonly createdAt!: Date;
    public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}

User.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        firstname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(36),
            allowNull: true
        },

        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        }
    },
    {
        sequelize,
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers: this is an issue with babel. See [issue 10579](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10579)

Either create a constructor on the class as follows:

```
export class User extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes> implements UserAttributes {
    public id: string;
    public firstname: string;
    ...

    constructor(values: any = {}, options: object = {}) {
        super(values, options)

        this.id = values.id
        this.firstname = values.firstname
        ...
    }
}
```

or create a reusable function as per the [example](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10579#issuecomment-574604414) in the GitHub discussion:

```
export default function restoreSequelizeAttributesOnClass(newTarget, self: Model): void {
  Object.keys(newTarget.rawAttributes).forEach((propertyKey: keyof Model) => {
    Object.defineProperty(self, propertyKey, {
      get() {
        return self.getDataValue(propertyKey);
      },
      set(value) {
        self.setDataValue(propertyKey, value);
      },
    });
  });
}
```

and call from within your constructor:

```
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    // hydrate the getters
    restoreSequelizeAttributesOnClass(new.target, this); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`create` returns Sequelize model instance which has a metadata and the record data is within nested object within metadata. (Try `console.log(created)` to see how the record is stored within Sequelize instance)

To get raw record data, you'll need `toJSON()`.

```
const user = created.toJSON();
console.info(user.id, user.firstname)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Emma but the default getters should be doing what you describe above and hydrating the properties - hence my question.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I could not reproduce your issue.  I got correct values from `console.info(created.id, created.firstname);`.  I am not using TS though.

Comment: Yes, it's a TS related issue